# Can nodes on a Kubernetes cluster have dynamic IP's OIC Classic

Tags: kubernetes, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I'm deploying K8s to the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure where while I can make sure that the public internet facing IP stays static even when the instances are restarted. But for some reason the private IP of the instances always changes. Which brings me to the question - can Kubernetes work with nodes who's IP changes after restarts?

This could be quite a noob question but I did try to read up online and I couldn't find a conclusive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, kubernetes can handle that case easily, and on OCI it works just fine.  The individual worker nodes will (using the kubelet on that host) call to the master IP, which we would recommend using a load balancer to front to achieve a static IP and allow you to change, scale, and otherwise adjust your master kubernetes control plane nodes as you wish, without disrupting the workers.

You can get a pretty slick setup currently with the terraform tooling for kubernetes that is published here:

https://github.com/oracle/terraform-kubernetes-installer

Comment: Thank you Eric. That answered my question pretty well. I'm actually stuck in a problem where my Private IP for the OCI machines has already changed due to a restart and I had the cluster working perfectly right before that. I went ahead and changed the master IP address in the .kube/config but well, the certificates use a different set of IP addresses apparently and hence I'm now getting an x.509 error "Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 100.65.20.234, not 100.65.9.6" - No idea how to "refresh" the certificates - if I can call it that.

Comment: Sorry @KaranKapoor ;; but did you find an exhaustive answer to your question ? , thanks

Comment: @Smaillns since I posted the question, Oracle Cloud Infra has come out with a generation 2 where Kubernetes is available as a managed cloud service where the consumer only pays for the worker nodes. In that environment, all these issues aren't there. If you're running on prem, the issue shouldn't exist in the first place itself, so I'm guessing if you're using OCI, this should answer your question. The Generation 1 OCI that I'd posted this question against isn't available anymore